# Classification Techniques In python

Tags: python, knn

I have found two codes online on Classification Techniques. One technique is Naive Bayes and the other one is KNn. I have used two datasets: one is [iris.data](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data) and the other one is [prima-indians-diabetes.data](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/pima-indians-diabetes/pima-indians-diabetes.data).

The prima indians dataset is working properly in Naive Bayes Algorithm and Iris.data is working correctly in KNn algorithm. But I want to compare both the algorithms which is possible only when one dataset runs in both of the algorithms.

I am attaching the algorithm of Naive bayes and KNn with both the datasets. and the respective tracebacks.

Naive Bayes with iris.data

```
# Example of Naive Bayes implemented from Scratch in Python
import csv
import random
import math


def loadCsv(filename):
    lines = csv.reader(open(filename, "rt"))
    dataset = list(lines)
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        dataset[i] = [float(x) for x in dataset[i]]
    return dataset


def splitDataset(dataset, splitRatio):
    trainSize = int(len(dataset) * splitRatio)
    trainSet = []
    copy = list(dataset)
    while len(trainSet) < trainSize:
        index = random.randrange(len(copy))
        trainSet.append(copy.pop(index))
    return [trainSet, copy]


def separateByClass(dataset):
    separated = {}
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        vector = dataset[i]
        if (vector[-1] not in separated):
            separated[vector[-1]] = []
        separated[vector[-1]].append(vector)
    return separated


def mean(numbers):
    return sum(numbers) / float(len(numbers))


def stdev(numbers):
    avg = mean(numbers)
    variance = sum([pow(x - avg, 2) for x in numbers]) / float(len(numbers) - 1)
    return math.sqrt(variance)


def summarize(dataset):
    summaries = [(mean(attribute), stdev(attribute)) for attribute in zip(*dataset)]
    del summaries[-1]
    return summaries


def summarizeByClass(dataset):
    separated = separateByClass(dataset)
    summaries = {}
    for classValue, instances in separated.items():
        summaries[classValue] = summarize(instances)
    return summaries


def calculateProbability(x, mean, stdev):
    exponent = math.exp(-(math.pow(x - mean, 2) / (2 * math.pow(stdev, 2))))
    return (1 / (math.sqrt(2 * math.pi) * stdev)) * exponent


def calculateClassProbabilities(summaries, inputVector):
    probabilities = {}
    for classValue, classSummaries in summaries.items():
        probabilities[classValue] = 1
        for i in range(len(classSummaries)):
            mean, stdev = classSummaries[i]
            x = inputVector[i]
            probabilities[classValue] *= calculateProbability(x, mean, stdev)
    return probabilities


def predict(summaries, inputVector):
    probabilities = calculateClassProbabilities(summaries, inputVector)
    bestLabel, bestProb = None, -1
    for classValue, probability in probabilities.items():
        if bestLabel is None or probability > bestProb:
            bestProb = probability
            bestLabel = classValue
    return bestLabel


def getPredictions(summaries, testSet):
    predictions = []
    for i in range(len(testSet)):
        result = predict(summaries, testSet[i])
        predictions.append(result)
    return predictions


def getAccuracy(testSet, predictions):
    correct = 0
    for i in range(len(testSet)):
        if testSet[i][-1] == predictions[i]:
            correct += 1
    return (correct / float(len(testSet))) * 100.0


def main():
    filename = 'E:\iris.data.csv'
    splitRatio = 0.67
    dataset = loadCsv(filename)
    trainingSet, testSet = splitDataset(dataset, splitRatio)
    print(('Split {0} rows into train={1} and test={2} rows').format(len(dataset), len(trainingSet), len(testSet)))
    # prepare model
    summaries = summarizeByClass(trainingSet)
    # test model
    predictions = getPredictions(summaries, testSet)
    accuracy = getAccuracy(testSet, predictions)
    print(('Accuracy: {0}%').format(accuracy))


main()
```

and the traceback for this is:

> runfile('C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/EE Codes/Knn with prima.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/EE Codes') Traceback (most recent call
>   last):
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2862, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/EE Codes/Knn with prima.py', wdir='C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/EE Codes')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 710, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 101, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/EE Codes/Knn with prima.py", line 63
>       print 'Train set: ' + repr(len(trainingSet))
>                         ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

KNn with prima indians:

```
# Example of kNN implemented from Scratch in Python

import csv
import random
import math
import operator

def loadDataset(filename, split, trainingSet=[] , testSet=[]):
    with open(filename, 'rt') as csvfile:
        lines = csv.reader(csvfile)
        dataset = list(lines)
        for x in range(len(dataset)-1):
            for y in range(4):
                dataset[x][y] = float(dataset[x][y])
            if random.random() < split:
                trainingSet.append(dataset[x])
            else:
                testSet.append(dataset[x])


def euclideanDistance(instance1, instance2, length):
    distance = 0
    for x in range(length):
        distance += pow((instance1[x] - instance2[x]), 2)
    return math.sqrt(distance)

def getNeighbors(trainingSet, testInstance, k):
    distances = []
    length = len(testInstance)-1
    for x in range(len(trainingSet)):
        dist = euclideanDistance(testInstance, trainingSet[x], length)
        distances.append((trainingSet[x], dist))
    distances.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    neighbors = []
    for x in range(k):
        neighbors.append(distances[x][0])
    return neighbors

def getResponse(neighbors):
    classVotes = {}
    for x in range(len(neighbors)):
        response = neighbors[x][-1]
        if response in classVotes:
            classVotes[response] += 1
        else:
            classVotes[response] = 1
    sortedVotes = sorted(classVotes.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return sortedVotes[0][0]

def getAccuracy(testSet, predictions):
    correct = 0
    for x in range(len(testSet)):
        if testSet[x][-1] == predictions[x]:
            correct += 1
    return (correct/float(len(testSet))) * 100.0

def main():
    # prepare data
    trainingSet=[]
    testSet=[]
    split = 0.67
    loadDataset('E:\pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv', split, trainingSet, testSet)
    print 'Train set: ' + repr(len(trainingSet))
    print 'Test set: ' + repr(len(testSet))
    # generate predictions
    predictions=[]
    k = 3
    for x in range(len(testSet)):
        neighbors = getNeighbors(trainingSet, testSet[x], k)
        result = getResponse(neighbors)
        predictions.append(result)
        print('> predicted=' + repr(result) + ', actual=' + repr(testSet[x][-1]))
    accuracy = getAccuracy(testSet, predictions)
    print('Accuracy: ' + repr(accuracy) + '%')

main()
```

And the traceback is:

> runfile('C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/EE Codes/Knn with prima.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/EE Codes') Traceback (most recent call
>   last):
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2862, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/EE Codes/Knn with prima.py', wdir='C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/EE Codes')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 710, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 101, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/EE Codes/Knn with prima.py", line 63
>       print 'Train set: ' + repr(len(trainingSet))
>                         ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What is the problem with these two bits of code?

Comment: You are probably using python 3, and the code you have is for python 2.  Modify any `print ...` (with a space) to be `print(...)`

Comment: Error messages are quite suited to be put into a code ( and quote on top) area to be better readable.

Comment: code formatting, fluff removal, change question to be more palatable